# sociable plugin

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I have used sociable plugin for my wordpress blog website. It works fine. But I noticed one problem. [image]

Normally linkedin share button does not show the counter bubble. If I click the button the counter will show.

[image]

I want normally the bubble displays with 0 count.

[image]

I found this code:

```
data-showZero="true"
```

But I did not know to put this code in any place. Could you please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the plugin does not appear to have that option. The data-showZero="true" is an attribute of the script tag LinkedIn uses to generate the button.

So the code would look something like this:

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/Share" data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-counter="right"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I have tried it. But it is not working.

Comment: Hm... Is there any chance you could post a code excerpt or a link to the page?

Answer (score 0):

Check this, maybe this will help you. 
http://webmodelling.com/webbits/socialmedia/default.aspx